# Cannot assign "25": "CashMovements.sale" must be a "Sale" instance. DJANGO

Tags: django, django-models

tengo el siguiente problema ojala puedan ayudarme
el error en si es el mensaje a la hora de guardar el id de mi venta en otra tabla
y me arroja
**Cannot assign "25": "CashMovements.sale" must be a "Sale" instance.**

Mi código en mi view

```
                    sale = Sale()
                    movement = CashMovements()
                    sale.employee_id = request.user.id
                    sale.client_id = int(request.POST['client'])
                    sale.payment_method = request.POST['payment_method']
                    sale.payment_condition = request.POST['payment_condition']
                    sale.type_voucher = request.POST['type_voucher']
                    sale.dscto = float(request.POST['dscto']) / 100
                    sale.save()
                    movement.total = sale.total
                    movement.sale = sale.id
                    movement.save()
```

Mi codigo en mis models

```
class CashMovements(models.Model):
    comentario = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    type = models.IntegerField(choices=type)
    sale = models.ForeignKey(Sale, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)


class Sale(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)
    employee = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)
    payment_condition = models.CharField(choices=payment_condition, max_length=50, default='contado')
    payment_method = models.CharField(choices=payment_method, max_length=50, default='efectivo')
    type_voucher = models.CharField(choices=voucher, max_length=50, default='ticket')
```

Soy nuevo en django, ojala puedan ayudarme a solucionar este error. Saludos

Comment: Yo no tengo ni idea de django pero solo el texto del error parece indicar que 'movement.sale = sale.id' debería ser 'movement.sale = sale'. ¿Has probado eso?

Comment: Te mereces una cerveza buen hombre. Muchas gracias!!

Comment: No hay de que :-)